# Passing and realloc a pointer into a funcion

Tags: c++, pointers, arguments

Hi i have a pointer that i want to manipulate in a funciont so i use a double pointer as argument of the function.. the problem is that when it call realloc is generated a segmantation fault.. here there is my code

```
 Loader::Loader(char* filename)
{
    file_desc=open(filename,O_RDONLY);
    if(file_desc<0) {
        std::cout<<"Error to open file..."<<std::endl;
    }       
    offsets=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));  
    this->detect_element(&offsets,'o',0);
}

void Loader:: detect_element(int** off,char p,int loffset,int end)
{
    char buffer;
    int count=1;
    int i=0;

    std::cout<<"Starting with caracter "<<p<<" from "<<loffset; 
    if(end!=-1)
    {
        std::cout<<" and ending to "<<end<<std::endl;
    }else{ 
        std::cout<<" and ending to the end"<<std::endl;
    }

    lseek(file_desc,loffset,SEEK_SET);
    while(read(file_desc,&buffer,1)>0)
    {
        if(buffer==p && state==CR)
        {
            *off[count-1]=i;
            *off=(int*)realloc(*off,
                sizeof(int)*(++count));
        }
        else if(buffer=='\n'){
            state=CR;
        }
        else{
            state=-1;
        }
        i++;
        if(end!=-1&&end==i){break;}
    }
    std::cout<<"Number of objs detected is "<<this->Length(*off)
        <<count<<std::endl<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Save yourself from pointer hell and use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: `*off=(int*)realloc(*off,
                sizeof(int)*(++count));` You have to save the pointer result in 1st place. Your code is leaking.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Overwriting the original pointer before checking the result of `realloc` is a bad idea.

Comment: @Olaf That additionally, yes.

Comment: Something [like this](http://ideone.com/5rVnyL) (Code commented out, but all of that malloc and realloc stuff replaced by `std::vector`).  All that code you wrote to do `realloc` is reduces to a single line.

Answer (score 0):

I solved using another  pointer  in the function  called int* offe and i work with it instead off. To the end I write *off=offe; and it works

Comment: First, I had a problem with pointers. I solved it by adding another pointer. Now I have two problems!

Comment: I solved without  using off (the argument of the function ) to use realloc. I 've worked with another pointer that to the end I used to save his memory  address into the off double pointer